# Use Python list in SQL query for column names

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, pymysql

I have a bunch of column names in a Python list. Now I need to use that list as the column names in a `SELECT` statement. How can I do that?

```
pythonlist = ['one', 'two', 'three']

SELECT pythonlist FROM data;
```

So far I have:

```
sql = '''SELECT  %s FROM data WHERE name = %s INTO OUTFILE filename'''

cur.execute(sql,(pythonlist,name))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot pass list of columns to select as a parameter to `cur.execute`. It should be part of your SQL expression, something like:

```
sql = "SELECT " + ",".join(pythonlist) + " FROM data WHERE name = %s INTO OUTFILE filename"
cur.execute(sql, (name,))
```

One thing to be aware of is that placeholder for a parameter value in the SQL depends on the database. If `%s` doesn't work try using `?` or `:1`. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle for more details.

Comment: I didn't know that `(name)` is different from `(name,)`. The additional comma makes it a tuple which execute needs. Thanks.